# How to convert 2 column matrix to dataframe table

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

I want to create a bigram wordcloud in R with package tau.

I got bigrams in a list as numeric. so I converted it to matrix but its without column name. I want it in a dataframe table so that I can create a bigram WordCloud with it.

Please find my code below and suggest a way out.

```
library(tau)
speech1 = Corpus(VectorSource(speech))
myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(speech1, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
bigrams = textcnt(speech1, n = 2, method = "string")
bigrams = bigrams[order(bigrams, decreasing = TRUE)
n = as.matrix(bigrams)
```

Please suggest a way on how can I create a wordcloud on bigram. unable to do with weka package

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data saved in ``speech``?

Comment: Its a simple text file which starts with: One year ago, I stood before you for the first time in this grand hall. I addressed the threats facing our world, and I presented a vision to achieve a brighter future for all of humanity.

Today, I stand before the United Nations General Assembly to share the extraordinary progress we’ve made.

In less than two years, my administration has accomplished more than almost any administration in the history of our country.

America’s -- so true. [Laughter] Didn’t expect that reaction, but that’s okay.

Comment: You can transform your bigram vector to dataframe by: test_data = data.frame(bigrams = names(bigrams), freq = bigrams). Than you can create a wordcloud something like this: wordcloud::wordcloud(test_data$bigrams, test_data$freq, max.words = 30). But something with your bigrams vector seams not right (at least when i try it with the samplecode). All bigrams get freq 1 this way.

Comment: Put it into the question and make the question so that someone can copy and paste what you did and have it run.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is the wordcloud, then check out this page : http://www.rpubs.com/rgcmme/PLN-09 , and here is a small adapted example from it:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
# sample data
filePath <- "http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/example-files/martin-luther-king-i-have-a-dream-speech.txt"
speech <- readLines(filePath)

speech1 = Corpus(VectorSource(speech))
myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(speech1, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
myDTM_mat <- as.matrix(myDTM)
myDTM_mat_sorted <- sort(rowSums(myDTM_mat),decreasing = TRUE)
myDTM_df <- data.frame(word = names(myDTM_mat_sorted), freq = myDTM_mat_sorted)
wordcloud(myDTM_df$word,
          myDTM_df$freq,
          max.words=100,
          random.order = F)
```

[image]